# Tabs not populating data on load firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using tabs in bootstrap, initially i have 4 tabs and when page loads it retrieve some data from firebase and put into tabs. But default selected tab remains empty, and when I click on other tabs those all tabs contains data. When I move back to previous (default selected tab) then it displays data.

Is it something about tabs? or am i doing something wrong?

Here is paste of some code i am using.

```
    <!--- https://pastebin.com/TyvAszg7 -->
```

Thanks For Your Help

ON LOAD

[image]

**AFTER CLICKING ON TAB 2**

[image]

**MOVING BACK TO 1st TAB**

[image]

Comment: you have to pull first tab data in Init function only. and if you are using angular then use ngOnInit method to load data.